# Variance of a mixed estimation model

Tags: mixed-model, variance

I am looking at a mixed estimation model and like to understand how to get the variance from it. For context I am providing the models I like to mix below before I continue to the question on the mixed model variance.

The first model is given as: $\pi = x\beta+u$

where:

- $\pi$ is the $n \times 1$ vector of CAPM equilibrium returns for the
  assets.
- $x$ is the $n \times n$ matrix $I_n$ which are the factor loadings
  for our model.
- $\beta$ is the $n \times 1$ vector of unknown means for the asset
  return process.
- $u$ is a $n \times n$ matrix of residuals from the regression
  where $E(u)=0$; and $Var(u)=E(u'u)=\Phi$ and $\Phi$ is non-singular.

The second model is given as: $q=p\beta+v$

where:

- $q$ is the $k \times 1$ vector of returns to be mixed with.
- $x$ is the $k \times n$ matrix in which returns of the second model
  are mapped to the first.
- $\beta$ is the $n \times 1$ vector of unknown means for the asset return
  process.
- $v$ is a $k \times k$ matrix of residuals from the regression where
  $E(v)=0$; and $Var(v)=E(v'v)=\Omega$ and $\Omega$ is non-singular.

The mixed model is then given by: 
$
\Bigg[\begin{matrix}
\pi\\
q
\end{matrix}\Bigg]
=
\Bigg[\begin{matrix}
x\\
p
\end{matrix}\Bigg]
\hat\beta+
\Bigg[\begin{matrix}
u\\
v
\end{matrix}\Bigg]
$

Now $\Bigg[\begin{matrix}u\\v\end{matrix}\Bigg]$ should be the error of the model and I am interested in the variance of the error. I understand that $Var(X) = E(XX) - E(X)^2$ since $E(X)$ is zero in both cases this would leave me with,according to my understanding at least:

$Var\Bigg(\Bigg[\begin{matrix}u\\v\end{matrix}\Bigg]\Bigg)=\Bigg[\begin{matrix}u\\v\end{matrix}\Bigg]'\Bigg[\begin{matrix}u\\v\end{matrix}\Bigg]$

I am, however, looking at a formulation reading:

$Var\Bigg(\Bigg[\begin{matrix}u\\v\end{matrix}\Bigg]\Bigg)=\Bigg[\begin{matrix}u\\v\end{matrix}\Bigg][\begin{matrix}u' v'\end{matrix}]$.

Are both representations of Var equivalent, is my understanding wrong or is something else missing?